# How do I prevent memory leak caused by context class in static fields

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, android-context

Help! I have a leak (at least I think so...)

The `instance` value below is my "port" into this class from static companion object. I had some thoughts of using applicationContext in some way (my TODO: comment)... because I get this memory leak warning... :

[image: Leak message]

To avoid this problem, and at the same time not needing the context parameter in every call to theese functions (I want to store the context in the class somehow, and get disposed of it when it dies), is there any good practice to the problem ?

```
...

class Repository private constructor(
        var context: Context
)
{
    /**
     * Repository class, class for all communication between database and external
     * sources
     * */

    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName

    val appDatabase: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context.applicationContext)

    //TODO: Test if better with applicationContext?

    companion object {
        private val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName

        @Volatile private var instance:Repository ?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context)= instance
                ?: synchronized(this){
                    instance
                            ?:Repository(context).also { instance = it }
                }
 

        fun liveDataUserResult(staffId: StaffType=StaffType.DRIVER) =
            instance?.liveDataUserResult(staffId = staffId)

        fun liveDataDepartmentResult(staffId: StaffType=StaffType.DRIVER) =
            instance?.liveDataDepartmentResult(staffId = staffId)

...

        fun liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath() = instance?.liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath()

...

    }

    fun liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath() =
        appDatabase.galleryItemDao().liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath(allText = context.getString(R.string.repository_all_text))

}
```

Comment: Have changed Q above to reflect my answer below the accepted answer. Otherwise it is the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not pass `Context` in the `Repository` except pass `AppDatabase` instance directly.

`AppDatabase` is used as `Singleton` throughout the application So you just initiate it once probably in Application class or in some other `Singleton`,  and use the same `Object` everywhere.

It will be easy to create/inject Dependencies if you use any dependency injection framework like Dagger2 or Dagger-Hilt.

You can remove var for constructor field to make it work then it will not hold the reference globally. Thx to @Henry Twist .

```
class Repository private constructor(context: Context) {
    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    var appDatabase: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context.applicationContext)
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: Repository? = null
        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(context: Context) = instance
            ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance
                    ?: Repository(context).also { instance = it }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but just as a side note, the only thing causing the actual leak is marking the `context` parameter as `var`. As you just use the `applicationContext` during the rest of initialisation it shouldn't cause any further problems!

Comment: Agreed . i was more focused on removing the need of calling `getInstance` multiple times . just call it once  and use the same instance. Updating the answer .

Comment: Thanx for answering both, I will test this shortly (it is Saturday evening for me (don't type and drink !), I'll check it out Sunday evening or so... )

Will accept/upvote then...

Comment: BTW: (When I am still somewhat sauber) I see that in my Repository class I have many references to `context.getString(R.string.somestring)`, since there "should" be no context reference in Repository, how do I cope with that, avoiding referencing context in the calls. Or am I left with Dagger2/Dagger-Hilt anyway. (Can't hardcode the texts, since I am in a multilanguage project )

Comment: In that case you can pass the application context into repository  instead of Activity context.  Or u can just set the I'd of string or other resources instead of setting it as a string.

Comment: Actually, you are right, it seems that I just need the applicationContext (further down the road) to solve that particular challenge ! 

So by doing it as you said, by skipping var and extract the applicationContext from context (applicationContext outlives context), and uses that for the context based references (as long as I don't do any cornercase typecasting), I am safe... ( leak free ?)

Anyhow: Thanx alot !! I accept your answer and posts my changes below.

Comment: yeah applicationContext should not be a leak candidate since its a `Singleton` . That's why i suggested a DI in first place since u do not have right now u can go this way .

Answer (score 1):

All credits to ADM and @Henry Twist above for an excellent answer (as I have accepted), but I will post my result here:

```
class Repository private constructor(
         context: Context
)
{
    /**
     * Repository class, class for all communication between database and external
     * sources
     * */

    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName

    val applicationContext: Context = context.applicationContext

    val appDatabase: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext)

    companion object {
        private val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName

        @Volatile private var instance:Repository ?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context)= instance
                ?: synchronized(this){
                    instance
                            ?:Repository(context).also { instance = it }
                }


        fun liveDataUserResult(staffId: StaffType=StaffType.DRIVER) =
            instance?.liveDataUserResult(staffId = staffId)
        fun liveDataDepartmentResult(staffId: StaffType=StaffType.DRIVER) =
            instance?.liveDataDepartmentResult(staffId = staffId)

...
              
        fun liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath() = instance?.liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath()

...

    }

    fun liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath() =
        appDatabase.galleryItemDao().liveDataGalleryItemSiteNoInUserPath(allText = applicationContext.getString(R.string.repository_all_text))
    
}
```

And, of course Dagger2 or Dagger-HILT will be more elegant.